# Merge [gin] and [go-gin] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

There is a web framework called [go-gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-gin) in Golang.
But there is also a tag called [gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gin) (its description: "GIN brings automatic dependency injection to GWT client-side code.")

Obviously, there is no connection between them.
But you could see some problems in the [gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gin) is about [go-gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-gin).

(So I think we maybe could rename the present tag[gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gin) to [gwt-gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt-gin). Not sure whether it is the best way but I think we need to take some measures.)

---

And also we could merge [gin-gonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gin-gonic) and [go-gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-gin)

Are there any differences?

[image: gin-gonic tag info excerpt]

[image: go-gin tag info excerpt]

Comment: It is a very god idea

Comment: Might as well update the [go-gin] tag excerpt to be less "what it is" and more "how to use the tag", and to remove the plagiarized sentence from the wiki...

Comment: missed opportunity to call the tag [gin-tonic]...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue here is that [gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gin) has [123 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgin%5D+%5Bgo%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0) that are also tagged with [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go). So this needs to be disambiguated first. I had a very quick look at the [questions without the go tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgin%5D+-%5Bgo%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0), and it looks like there aren't any other usages of [gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gin) apart from [gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt) and [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go). To set this right, we will have to:

1. Add the [go-gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-gin) to the [123 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgin%5D%20%5Bgo%5D%20is%3Aq&mixed=0) with [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) already, and remove the [gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gin) from them. (Which needs a team of dedicated users)
2. Rename [gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gin) to [gwt-gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt-gin). (Which needs a moderator)

Once these two are done, we should be good to go.

Answer (score 5):

[gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gin) is now disambiguated, thanks to all that participated.

**Retagging progress**

This is the [list of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgin%5D+%5Bgo%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0) that we need to retag with [go-gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-gin) instead of [gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gin). Feel free to log updates here unless you are planning to go through all of the questions in one [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go).

**Retagging isn't just removal and addition of the tag**

We would be cleaning up the tag in the process of retagging. Along with updating the post with the correct tag, you can also help by:

- editing the post to make them better than they were before
- flagging/closing questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based

---

Slowly, but steadily: <s>100</s> <s>90</s> <s>39</s> none left

Comment: I really don't think we need a progress post for retagging, but it doesn't hurt to have one! I have updated it with some additional guidance.  :)

Comment: I observed that it usually appears on burnination requests (at least it used to), so decided to add one (usually I do that on my proposals). Noted the second guideline - I usually only do the first when editing, thank you!

Comment: @BhargavRao I've just finished the last one

Comment: @DavidBuck, TylerH - thank you for the retagging! I was starting to think I am the only one who noticed :)